# images do not match the card from pokeapi.co

Tags: javascript, pokeapi

I'm having problems with my front end in JavaScript. The names are correct, but the images do not match. it is not getting the pokemon data in the correct order.

[image]

```js
let currentPageUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokémon/';

window.onload = async() => {
  try {
    await loadCharacters(currentPageUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('Erro ao carregar cards');
  }

  const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', loadNextPage);

  const backButton = document.getElementById('back-button');
  backButton.addEventListener('click', loadPreviousPage);
};

async function loadCharacters(url) {
  const mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
  mainContent.innerHTML = '';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();

    responseJson.results.forEach((character) => {
          const card = document.createElement("div");
          card.style.backgroundImage = `url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${character.url.replace(/\D/g, "")}.png')`

          card.className = "cards"
          const characterNameBG = document.createElement("div")
          characterNameBG.className = "character-name-bg"
          const characterName = document.createElement("span")
          characterName.className = "character-name"
          characterName.innerText = `${character.name}`
          characterNameBG.appendChild(characterName)
          card.appendChild(characterNameBG)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add RELEVANT HTML and framework from CDN

Comment: So you obviously have issues with this statement `card.style.backgroundImage = \`url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${character.url.replace(/\D/g, "")}.png')\``

Comment: What is the first URL you use? `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokémon/` does not work
`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/` works and `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/` works

Comment: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/` will get you a bulbasaur and `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/` will get you a bunch of image URLs